# pointer problems in C? function to order inputs, return as string and print in main

Tags: c, string, pointers, types, return-value

I want to write a function that will take two integers, three times, and then return them ordered by the first integer and (for now) print them in main (though eventually I plan/hope to switch to a file-based structure to store and organize data), but I think I might have an issue with my pointers cause even when I skip concatenations (which looks like might also be another separate issue), everything Ive tried has main print a string (or no string) which never matches the input, but the print statements suggest all the looped assignments are working properly.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char * entry()
{
    int n;
    int level;
    char habit1entry[6];
    char habit2entry[6];
    char habit3entry[6];
    for (int c = 0; c< 3; c++){
        printf("Habit #\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("Level:\n");
        scanf("%d", &level);
        switch (n)
        {
            case 1:;
                sprintf(habit1entry, "|%d|%d|\n", n,level);
                printf("n = %d\n",n); 
                printf("%s\n",habit1entry);
                continue;
            case 2:;
                sprintf(habit2entry, "|%d|%d|\n", n,level);
                printf("n = %d\n",n);
                printf("%s\n",habit2entry);
                continue;
            case 3:;
                sprintf(habit3entry, "|%d|%d|\n", n,level);
                printf("n = %d\n",n);
                printf("%s\n",habit3entry);
                continue;
        }
    }
    strcat(habit2entry,habit3entry);
    printf("%s\n",habit2entry);
    strcat(habit1entry,habit2entry);
    printf("%s\n",habit1entry);
    char *fullEntry=habit3entry;
    printf("%s\n",fullEntry);

    return strdup(&fullEntry[0]);
}
int main(){
    const char * dataEntry = entry();
    //strcpy(dataEntry,entry());
    printf("Data:\n%s",dataEntry);
}
```

heres an example of the output(after the correct prints inside the switch cases) for an input of 3 2 1 1 2 2:
"

|2|2|

|1|1|
|2|2|
|2|2|
|��
|2|2|
|��
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
Aborted (core dumped) "

p.s. Sorry if this all sounds silly, this is my first C project (and first real stack overflow post, plz b gentl) coming from jumping around between java, python and clojure and I would like to take an operating systems class that allows you to start without knowing C but expects you to pick it up on your own and its hard finding material that explains C concepts in a scope that matches my background knowledge and current learning constraints in terms of time available for taking deep dives through explanations that for me have ended up mostly being either hopelessly esoteric, incredibly case-specific or overly-simplistic/redundant/unhelpful explanations of programming concepts I picked up in other languages. Dont mean to complain or harp on and its probably good to get practice with different methods of asking questions and finding answers for problems like these, but the learning curve for understanding things like this (setting up the compiler/json files involved spending hours only to discover that mcafee was deleting my exes which I became convinced was a symptom of a virus, only to have the behavior stop after I restarted for a minor routine windows update and I have no idea why) outside of a traditional framework sometimes seems more like a wall  and I'm worried that maybe I should revise my approach to avoid wasting too much of my time banging my head against a series of very sturdy walls. any and all advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Awesome! really appreciate the quick and thorough replies! great community! I think I intialized small arrays before I understood the strcat function (/idk the conventions yet) and planned to concat them all at once instead of in steps and forgot to make the appropriate space when I switched and then I think I had switched out habit1entry for habit3entry to skip around the concatenations for debugging purposes while trying to figure out how to write them and what was wrong with my output and then forgot that I did that because I was focused on the wrong output that the old array sizes produced

Answer (score 0):

Abstracting form the logic of the program, you have plenty of issues there:

1. You do not provide enough space for the strings
2. Your switch is not very related to your for loop
3. Names of the variables do not matter for you - but they matter for the program . Be more careful.
4. probably more but I forgot already

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char * entry()
{
    int n;
    int level;
    char habit1entry[21] = "";
    char habit2entry[14] = "";
    char habit3entry[7] = "";
    for (int c = 1; c < 4; c++){
        printf("Habit #\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("Level:\n");
        scanf("%d", &level);
        switch (c)
        {
            case 1:;
                sprintf(habit1entry, "|%d|%d|\n", n,level % 10);
                printf("n = %d\n",n); 
                printf("He1: %s\n",habit1entry);
                continue;
            case 2:;
                sprintf(habit2entry, "|%d|%d|\n", n,level % 10);
                printf("n = %d\n",n);
                printf("He2 = %s\n",habit2entry);
                continue;
            case 3:;
                sprintf(habit3entry, "|%d|%d|\n", n,level % 10);
                printf("n = %d\n",n);
                printf("He3 = %s\n",habit3entry);
                continue;
        }
    }
    strcat(habit2entry,habit3entry);
    printf("H2 + H3 = %s\n",habit2entry);
    strcat(habit1entry,habit2entry);
    printf("H1 + H2 = %s\n",habit1entry);
    char *fullEntry=habit1entry;
    printf("FE: %s\n",fullEntry);

    return strdup(fullEntry);
}
int main(){
    const char * dataEntry = entry();
    //strcpy(dataEntry,entry());
    printf("Data:\n%s",dataEntry);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! does the switch need to be related to the for loop? my goal here was to require 3 inputs, but allow them to be inserted in any order and then be "logged" in order of habit #. I was actually about to add a default since I would like to only accept inputs of 1 2 and 3 (and eventually tighten up make sure each case gets triggered only 1 time). Since the input for the habit level is the condition that determines its variable assignment, I thought it would make a natural switch variable. Is this bad practice?

Comment: @RedBeansAndRice I have no clue what the switch is for. If you want to have 3 valid entries you must add much more logic into the program

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the weird and wonderful world of C.

I have not actually compiled and run your program yet, just had a quick read through and though I give you my first thoughts.

The way your program is written is primed to generate stack overflows. You have three (very little) character arrays defined on the stack habitxentry, so your sprintf's will most certainly blow your stack unless both the Habit and Level inputs are less than 10. Habit is alright because your switch only allows 1, 2 or 3. Your switch does nothing if Habit is anything else.

As a side note: sprintf is not really the function to use in our security minded world. snprintf is a better choice. Not really an issue here per se as you are not passing in user supplied data but still, it's not a good habit to cultivate.

Next you strcat your character arrays together, virtually guarantying a stack violation, but lets assume this works; you are concatenating 2 and 3 into habit2entry and then 1 and 2 into habit1entry.

Next you are creating a pointer to habit3entry (not habit1entry) and returning a duplicate.

By doing so you are allocating heap in a mildy obscure manner. The callee will be responsible for freeing this memory.
I always preferred to explicitly malloc the memory and then strcpy (or memcpy) the data in.
Now when you grep your code, you only have to look for malloc.
Also, someone using the function will notice the malloc, see you have returned to pointer and realize that freeing it will now be his problem.

In order to avoid these problems some programmers leave it to the caller to supply a buffer to the function. The reasoning is that a function is supposed to do one thing and one thing only. In this case you are doing two things, you allocate memory and you fill that memory.

In your switch statement I noticed that each of your case labels are followed by an empty statement.
the semicolon at the end of that line is not necessary: write "case 1:" not "case 1:;"
You also use continue at the end of each block. This is allowed but "break" is more appropriate.
In this case it will have the same effect but normally you have more statements after the switch.
Now the difference will become apparent. Continue will jump straight to the top of the loop, break will break out of the switch and continue executing there.

Hope this gives you some insight.

Good luck.

Comment: `written is primed to generate stack overflows` there are no stack overflows there. There are only out of bounds accesses.

Comment: `Next you strcat your character arrays together, virtually guarantying a stack violation` please explain. This function only works with the strings, and strings are arrays of `char`. So how can you use it without the strings?

Comment: `The reasoning is that a function is supposed to do one thing and one thing only.` very interesting but wrong. Functions can do many things.If function return pointer it has to reference to the object which will exist when function returns. How it is archived is up to programmer.

Comment: good to know about snprintf!! hard to keep track/find best practice recommendations while trying to pick up a language from a hodge podge of internet sources so definitely appreciate the pointer!

Comment: At certain points while switching between strcat and strcpy versions I managed to return only one case input and in another one case was copied too many times, so I thought I might be misunderstanding how scopes are established in switch statements so I was trying to make sure the break statemnts wernt somehow breaking out of the larger for loop by not closing the case scope(which i figured wasnt happening, but couldnt see a logical explanation of my output so I thought Id test it, though I probly shouldve been mindful to cut it from my post since I didn't actually think it was working)

Comment: @ P__J__ You are right, I was talking about an out of bound access not a stack overflow, I stand corrected. Second comment again I should have used out of bound. There is no issue about strings being arrays of char, the issue is that there is not enough space reserved on the stack to hold the amount of characters he wants to copy into it using strcat.

Comment: Third comment. Of course functions can do a multitude of things. I am not saying that a function is only allowed to do one thing, I am saying that general practice prefers functions to have one clearly defined goal.
Of course that goal could be to create and initialize a new object and return a pointer to that. However in my programming career I have never created a function that 1. creates a new object, 2. get user input and 3. initialise this new object based on the user input.

Comment: I know this is a simple example but given the fact that he is just learning C I thought the one responsibility practice might be helpful to know.